# Exporting R 3 dataframes to 3 different sheets in the same excel workbook

Tags: r, export-to-excel, r-xlsx

I am attempting to export 3 dataframes to  3 different sheets in the same excel workbook, this is the code I used:

```
write.xlsx(x = df1,file = "Report.xlsx",sheetName = "pr1")
write.xlsx(x = df2,file = "Report.xlsx",sheetName = "pr2", append = TRUE)
write.xlsx(x = df3,file = "Report.xlsx",sheetName = "pr3", append = TRUE)
```

When I run this, I only see  **sheet pr3**
Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

Also, using `write_xlsx`

```
library(writexl)
write_xlsx(list(pr1 = df1, pr2 = df2, pr3 = df3), path = "Report.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 1):

try this i'm sure this will help

```
datasets <- list("pr1" = df1,"pr2" = df2,"pr3" = df3)
write.xlsx(datasets,file = "Report.xlsx")
```

Comment: Are you using package `xlsx` or package `openxlsx`?

Comment: openxlsx package